# Looping through an array and printing a set range to PDF in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print out some timetables to PDF. I have the list of code names for each person in a worksheet called Allocations.

I'm trying to get it to loop through the code names and place each one in cell B28 on the Individualised worksheet - this will display that individuals timetable.

I then want it to print ranges A1:K28 to PDF and save each one with the code in a folder in my documents called PDFs.

Any help much appreciated!

This code is what I have tried testing just to see if I could get it to make a loop and print. However, this loops but doesn't print.

```
Sub iterate()
Dim vars As Variant, i As Long
vars = Array(300, 800, 2700, 2800)
For i = LBound(vars) To UBound(vars)
[B28] = vars(i)

ThisFile = Range("A9").Value
Sheets("Individualised").Range("A1:K28").ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\PDF" & ThisFile & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=Falses

Next I
```

Workable version:

```
Sub iterate()
Dim vars As Variant, i As Long
vars = Array(300, 800, 2700, 2800)
For i = LBound(vars) To UBound(vars)
[B28] = vars(i)

ThisFile = Range("B28").Value
Sheets("Individualised").Range("A1:K28").ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\PDF\" & ThisFile & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i
```

Comment: What do you mean by "list of codes"? What does "loop through the codes in cell B28" should also mean? What did you try by your own?

Comment: List of codes - Code names for each individual person. I would like it to place the next code name in cell B28 and then print the range I identified. I tried to just get it first of all just to loop through an array and then print. I got the loop working by writing some of the codes but it wouldn't print.

Posted the code I tried in original post

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us your code, even if it does not work as you want. You need to prove that did something by your own...

Comment: Added the code to the original post.

Comment: Does the code return any error? What value does `ThisFile` variable have? If it has one and no error raised, you should find the pdf files on the path "C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents" with a name obtained by concatenation of "PDF & ThisFile & ".pdf". You missed a backslash after "PDF". If the backslash is not contained in `ThisFile` variable...

Comment: There is a typo on your code `OpenAfterPublish:=Falses`. The last `s`, but not having `Option Explicit` on top of the module, to be forced to declare all variables, it will  not affect the code, I think.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the printing. However, now it prints 1 PDF named 'PDF' I assume it is printing the other 3 but overwriting it with the same name

Comment: You did not answer my question... How `ThisFile` is built? How does it look? Is it empty? If it is the same all the time, the next pdf file overwrites the previous ones. But put a backslash after PDF: "Filename:="C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\PDF\", in order to save in folder "PDF".

Comment: Added to code. It now prints each PDF. However, it adds the word PDF to the start. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: I told you in my previous comment. Put a backslash as I recommended...